# Compare two CSV files based on key field: find modifications, new records and deletions with Python

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I have two CSV files, with same fields, let's say:

```
ID,NAME,SURNAME,HOME_ADDRESS,NUMBER_OF_PHONE_LINES,PREFIX,PHONE_NUMBER,EMAIL
```

I would like to compare the two CSV files, and find:

- records that are in file A and not in B (comparison simply based on three fields: ID, PREFIX and PHONE_NUMBER)
- records that are in file B and not in A (always based on the above fields)
- records that have same ID, PREFIX and PHONE_NUMBER but have different informations in other fields, e.g. different EMAIL or different EMAIL and HOME_ADDRESS.

And, finally, split these infos in three different files.

Anybody has an idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Make a class. Make a comparison operator. Read the files into sets (or possibly order the entries if you want to do things manually). Use set difference and intersection. Write the result to three file. By the way I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: your question says "give me code", that is not you would suppose to ask on SO. for reading,writing csv[http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html], after reading both files, it merely a simple program. Try python docs first, paste what you have tried if you are having any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give an overall idea. This is not tested, and is just to describe the idea, not a solution!

```
# open files...
csv_a = f1.readlines()
box_a = [x.split(',') for x in csv_a]
#similar to load list of lists for box_b
box_in_a_not_b = []
box_in_b_not_a = []
box_match_not_perfect = []
while box_a:
    line = box_a.pop()
    flag=0
    while box_b:
        bline = box_b.pop()
        if line[0]=bline[0] and line[6]=bline[6] and line[7]=bline[7] # 6 & 7 being PREFIX and PHONE_NUMBER indexes
           if not all([line[z]==bline[z] for z in range(len(line))]):
               box_match_not_perfect.append(line)
               box_match_not_perfect.append(bline) # keeps both instances in the 3d file
        else:
            box_in_b_not_a.append(bline)
            flag =1 # match not found, so add line from A to the file with unique

    #end of while box_b
    if flag==1:
        box_in_a_not_b.append(line)

#end of while box_a
in_a_not_b = [','.join(z) for z in box_in_a_not_b] # to get list of csv lines
# use another '\n'.join() to get one big multiline string, or write line by lie to the file
# to save box_in_a_not_b, box_in_b_not_a and box_in_match_not_perfect in corresponding files
#...
```